# did DBCC CHECKDB

Tags: sql, sql-server, corruption, dbcc

Help getting crushed by this

i did DBCC CHECKDB and one of the DB gave Msg 823, Level 24, State 2, Line 2 I/O error 21(The device is not ready.) detected during read at offset 0x0000000001c000 in file 'E:\MSSQL2000\Data\FTSWE_Data.MDF'.

I was working on a remote server, from my, local host accessing a remote DB.

Also i was on VPN.

Answer (score 2):

Probably belongs on serverfault. Anyhow, I would contact whomsoever is hosting the box, it seems like there is a nasty disk error brewing. I hope you have backups, etc.

Comment: That's good, but are you sure something important, like the hard drive your data lives on, isn't failing?

Answer (score 0):

Error 823 is nasty. It's a hard IO error

See Paul Randall's [site for "823".](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/search.aspx?q=823) he wrote DBCC CHECK DB

> ...it says that an I/O operation failed
>   at the OS level and the I/O subsystem
>   is causing corruption...

I'd double check your backups *now* and call them to make sure they know something is wrong.